# Formating Dates (YYYY-MM-DD to 2 Dec 2018) - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert start and end date that I get as string, to something like this:

```
2 Dec - 10 Dec 2018
```

I get the date in this format: `2018-12-02`

So for start date, I don't want the year to show (but I will need a year for something else as well). What is the best way to do this?

I tried with:

```
var startDate = new Date(filteredArray[i].start_date).toDateString();
```

But I don't know what format to add, I thought I could pass format to `toDateString` but it didn't work.

Comment: [`Moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `filteredArray[i].start_date` contains the start date and `filteredArray[i].end_date` contains the end date.

The method you are using works rather well. You can use `.split(" ")` to split the date to get Day, Month, Date, and Year respectively

Example:

```js
var filteredArray = [{"start_date": "2018-12-02", "end_date": "2018-12-10"}];
var startDate = new Date(filteredArray[0].start_date).toDateString();
var endDate = new Date(filteredArray[0].end_date).toDateString();

var sD = startDate.split(" ");
var eD = endDate.split(" ");

console.log(sD[2] + ' ' + sD[1] + ' - ' + eD[2] + ' ' + eD[1] + ' ' + eD[3]);
```